# how to read a midi file

Tags: c#, midi

I am trying to find sample c# (forms) code to open a midi file and dump the notes and duration (by channel) into lists. I saw nAudio and Drywetmidi.

Did some digging and so far have this using nAudio. Am I going wrong somewhere?

```
    public void ConvertFile()
    {
        MidiFile midiFile = new MidiFile("test.mid", false);
        for (int track = 0; track < midiFile.Tracks; track++)
        {
            IList<MidiEvent> trackEvents = midiFile.Events[track];


            string noteChannel = "", noteName = "";
            int noteDuration = 0;
            long noteStart = 0;

            foreach (MidiEvent midiEvent in trackEvents)
            {

                if (midiEvent is NoteOnEvent noteOnEvent)
                {
                    noteChannel = noteOnEvent.Channel + " ";
                    noteStart = noteOnEvent.AbsoluteTime;
                    if (noteOnEvent.Velocity > 0)
                    {
                        noteName += noteOnEvent.NoteName + "   ";
                        noteDuration = noteOnEvent.NoteLength;
                    }
                }

            }
            if (noteName != "")
                MessageBox.Show(noteName, noteChannel);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With [DryWetMIDI](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi) you can easily get all notes with this code:

```
MidiFile file = MidiFile.Read("My MIDI file.mid");
IEnumerable<Note> notes = file.GetNotes();
```

`Note` has properties `Time`, `Length`, `Channel`, `Velocity`, `OffVelocity`.